# How to know if Delete method was successful in PayPal Web API using PayPal.Net SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, paypal

Below is some code from PayPal Samples for .Net where an invoice is being deleted. I downloaded this from : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/tree/master/Samples/Source. The code that deletes an invoice does so by making the following call `createdInvoice.Delete` which returns a void.

**Question** : How does one know that delete was successful since this method returns a void?

**PayPal code to Delete a created invoice using NET SDK for PayPal**

```
// ^ Ignore workflow code segment
#region Track Workflow
this.flow.AddNewRequest("Create the invoice", invoice);
#endregion

// Create the invoice
var createdInvoice = invoice.Create(apiContext);

// ^ Ignore workflow code segment
#region Track Workflow
this.flow.RecordResponse(createdInvoice);
this.flow.AddNewRequest("Delete the invoice");
#endregion

createdInvoice.Delete(apiContext);//This method returns a void, so how we   
                                  //know it succeeded?????

// ^ Ignore workflow code segment
#region Track Workflow
this.flow.RecordActionSuccess("Invoice deleted successfully.");
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I found that the `Delete` method throws an exception if delete fails. Hence, one can safely assume that if there was no exception thrown when call to `Delete` method was made, then the delete of invoice succeeded.